# Combine related nested list element vectors into matrices

Tags: r, list

I have a list where each list element itself holds another list with several names objects. Each of these named object is a vector of the same length. My goal is to efficiently combine the related objects (those of the same name) into a matrix by concatening vectors.

Here's an example of the type of structure I'm working with. However, in the current application it's coming from mclapply as it is a parallelized multilevel model, and I don't think there's a way around getting a list of lists back.

```
> test=lapply(1:2,function(x){out = list(); out$t=rnorm(3)+x; out$p =rnorm(3)+ x+.1; return(out)})
> test
[[1]]
[[1]]$t
[1] 0.5950165 0.8827352 0.5614947

[[1]]$p
[1] 2.6144102 1.9688743 0.6241944


[[2]]
[[2]]$t
[1] 2.562030 1.832571 3.018756

[[2]]$p
[1] 1.7431969 0.5305784 2.6935106
```

Here's a crude way to accomplish what I want

```
> t.matrix = cbind(test[[1]]$t,test[[2]]$t)
> t.matrix
           [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  2.2094525 2.634907
[2,] -0.2822453 2.440666
[3,]  1.1704518 2.483424
```

but instead I'd like to be able to do this for a very long list (around 1 million elements), and my current solution doesn't scale.

I suppose I could use a for loop, but it seems like there must be a better way to do it with clever use of reduce or unlist or sapply or something like that.

Comment: It's always nice when you're sharing these kinds of questions to use `set.seed()` so that we can compare the output we get with what you intend to get.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'll be sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
test <- lapply(1:4, function(x) { 
          out = list(); out$t=rnorm(3)+x; out$p =rnorm(3)+ x+.1; return(out)})

do.call(cbind, lapply(test, function(X) X[["t"]]))
## do.call(cbind, lapply(test, "[[", "t"))          ## Or, equivalently 
#           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4] 
# [1,] 0.7382887 0.9248296 4.205222 5.847823 
# [2,] 3.0321069 3.6806652 3.324739 3.695195 
# [3,] 2.3611483 1.9305901 1.574586 4.287534
```

Or, to process both sets of list elements at once:

```
elems <- c("t", "p")
sapply(elems, function(E) {
     do.call(cbind,
             lapply(test, function(X) {
                 X[[E]]
             }))
}, simplify=FALSE)
# $t
#           [,1]       [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
# [1,] 1.9226614 0.66463844 2.558517 2.743381
# [2,] 3.0026400 0.03238983 2.195404 3.824127
# [3,] 0.9371057 3.54638107 2.968717 2.434471
# 
# $p
#           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
# [1,] 0.8544413 2.942780 4.693698 4.158212
# [2,] 0.7172070 2.381438 4.869630 3.503361
# [3,] 3.1369674 2.464447 2.484968 3.626174
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using `unlist(test, recursive = FALSE)`. It needs to be done in more than one step though, if you want "p" and "t" to be separate. Here they are together:

```
temp <- do.call(cbind, unlist(test, recursive = FALSE))
temp
             t         p        t        p
[1,] 0.3735462 2.6952808 2.487429 1.794612
[2,] 1.1836433 1.4295078 2.738325 3.611781
[3,] 0.1643714 0.2795316 2.575781 2.489843
```

Separating them out is pretty straightforward:

```
temp[, colnames(temp) %in% "t"]
#              t        t
# [1,] 0.3735462 2.487429
# [2,] 1.1836433 2.738325
# [3,] 0.1643714 2.575781
temp[, colnames(temp) %in% "p"]
#              p        p
# [1,] 2.6952808 1.794612
# [2,] 1.4295078 3.611781
# [3,] 0.2795316 2.489843
```

Here's the data I used:

```
set.seed(1)
test <- lapply(1:2, function(x) {
  out = list()
  out$t=rnorm(3)+x
  out$p =rnorm(3)+ x+.1
  return(out)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, upvote for you. However, one hesitation I have with unlist is that the benchmarking I've seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4013388/288545) indicates that using unlist with names turned on is much much slower. I suppose I could use your solution and turn the useNames flag off, but that would make the reconstruction a bit trickier.

Comment: @DanielKessler, Thanks for sharing that link. I had no idea that retaining names when using unlist made the function that much slower! I guess a workaround if you know your data are nicely organized would be to select the odd numbered columns and the even numbered columns in the end, but that might be error prone. I think Josh's approach is definitely the most appropriate here.