# Combining deeply-nested vectors from multiple lists

Tags: r, list, data-structures

I wish to combine equivalent, deeply-nested columns from all elements of a reasonably long list. What I would like to do, though it's not possible in R, is this:

```
combined.columns <- my.list[[1:length(my.list)]]$my.matrix[,"my.column"]
```

The only thing I can think of is to manually type out all the elements in `cbind()` like this:

```
combined.columns <- cbind(my.list[[1]]$my.matrix[,"my.column"], my.list[[2]]$my.matrix[,"my.column"], . . . )
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839523/combine-related-nested-list-element-vectors-into-matrices) is pretty close to what I need, but I can't figure out how to make it work for the extra level of nesting.

There must be a more elegant way of doing this, though. Any ideas?

Comment: In that linked question I would do `sapply(test, c, recursive = TRUE)` to get in down to a matrix. Could you provide a bit of your data?

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7c13g36e89vlnb/sample.data.RData?dl=0) is some of my data. In reality, I want to combine the vector `X.mbl.vartime1[[i]]$per.bin.rates[,"in.rate"]` across all elements of the list (although it could just as well be any column-within-a-matrix-within-a-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all your matrices have the same column name you wish to extract you could use `sapply`

```
set.seed(123)
my.list <- vector("list")
my.list[[1]] <- list(my.matrix  = data.frame(A=rnorm(10,sd=0.3), B=rnorm(10,sd=0.3)))
my.list[[2]] <- list(my.matrix  = data.frame(C=rnorm(10,sd=0.3), B=rnorm(10,sd=0.3)))
my.list[[3]] <- list(my.matrix  = data.frame(D=rnorm(10,sd=0.3), B=rnorm(10,sd=0.3)))

sapply(my.list, FUN = function(x) x$my.matrix[,"B"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Free data:

```
myList <- list(list(myMat = matrix(1:10, 2, dimnames=list(NULL, letters[1:5])),
                    myVec = 1:10),
               list(myMat = matrix(10:1, 2, dimnames=list(NULL, letters[1:5])),
                    myVec = 10:1))
```

We can get column `a` of `myMat` a few different ways. Here's one that uses `with`.

```
sapply(myList, with, myMat[,"a"])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   10
# [2,]    2    9
```

This `mapply` one might be better for a more recursive type problem. It works too and might be faster than `sapply`.

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) x[[y]][,z] , myList, "myMat", "a")
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   10
# [2,]    2    9
```